# Como coloco um required no input sem a tag form?

Tags: javascript, html5, input

Sempre que coloco a propriedade required, o meu scrip para de funcionar.

Como posso inserir um `required` no input sem a tag `form`?

```js
var cont1 = 1;
var cont2 = 2;
var cont3 = 3;

document.getElementById("btnSubmit").onclick = function() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("nome-radio");
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {

    if (radios[i].checked) {
      console.log("Escolheu: " + radios[i].value);
      if (radios[i].value == cont1) {
        console.log("ola 1");
      } else if (radios[i].value == cont2) {
        console.log("ola 2");
      } else if (radios[i].value == cont3) {
        console.log("ola 3");
      }

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <title>Exemplo</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="nome-radio" value=1>Teste 1
      <input type="radio" name="nome-radio" value=2>Teste 2
      <input type="radio" name="nome-radio" value=3>Teste 3
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Entrar" />

    </p>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: O que você quer fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Bom eu testei no codepen e seu código não tem problema nenhum basta colocar o required em um dos radio-buttons já que todos os "name" tem valores iguais basta adicionar o required em apenas um elemento:

```
https://codepen.io/lucasbpereira/pen/wvgmxGO
```

```
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <title>Exemplo</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="nome-radio" value=1 required>Teste 1
      <input type="radio" name="nome-radio" value=2>Teste 2
      <input type="radio" name="nome-radio" value=3>Teste 3
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Entrar" />

    </p>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```